# Need ChromeDriver built in Mono

Tags: c#, macos, selenium, mono, ninja

I am using C# WebDriver to automate a web application. Everything is written targetting Windows already. But now there is a need to get it ready for Mac as well. Selenium webdriver launches Chrome using ChromeDriver.exe. This exe can be launched in Windows using C# Process class; but not in Mac using the same class in Mono. The solution seems to be building ChromeDriver in Mono. I have got the ChromeDriver source from github. But having difficulty in building the same.
The problem statement is: how to build ChromeDriver.exe with Mono. I am using Xamarin Studio (which is the Development IDE I am using to develop in C# on Mac). So my aim is to load the ChromeDriver sources in Xamarin Studio and build it. But when I pulled the sources of ChromeDriver, I see several C files without any project file, as in *.vcxproj. Searching on this topic what I find out is that it could be built using Ninja. There is some command "ninja -C out\Release chromedriver" that is going to do it for me. So I fetched the Ninja sources from github. But when I try to run the build command, then it complains out/Release File or Directory not existing. It is indeed not existing inside the folder where I fetched Ninja. The only information I have is that the out folder will be there once I generate the Ninja files. But I am completely ignorant about how to do it or what are the pre-requisites for it.
Coming back to why I need it: In the selenium webdriver code the ChromeDriver is launched using C# process class.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = <Full Path of ChromeDriver.exe>;
p.UseShellExecute = false;
p.Start();
```

This C# code snippet works in Windows, but not on Mac. I use Xamarin Studio to debug it. And the error I get at the line p.start() is "No process attached to the object p". Next I build a simple console application in C# using Xamarin Studio on Mac; i.e. the output exe is built with Mono framework. And I use this exe's path instead of ChromeDriver in the above code. And p.Start() gets executed successfully with no error.

Hence the problem comes down to having a Mono version of the ChromeDriver.exe. In chromedriver's site they have ChromeDriver.exe for Windows, ChromeDriver.dmg for Mac but no Mono version of it. I am looking for any of the 3 following solutions:
 1. If the ChromeDriver.exe built with Mono is already there somewhere uploaded, nothing better that that. 
 2. The steps I can try to build the ChromeDriver sources 
    (https://github.com/scheib/chromium/tree/master/chrome/test/chromedriver)
    with Mono. 
 3. Skip building it altogether and find some other way to launch the ChromeDriver.exe in        Mac.

I am scratching my head with all these for the last couple of days :( . Any help will be largely appreciated! Do let me know if any more info is required. Please help..

Thanks in advance,
Deb

Comment: Any error messages you are getting would also be helpful.

Comment: What errors are you getting and post the full stack trace. These words mean nothing without errors and code to back it up.

Comment: Edited the post with more details..

Comment: Note that the program won't be ChromeDriver.exe on Mac unless it is created with the Windows extension for compatibility with Windows.

Comment: Hi @Deb just curious if you were ever able to run WebDriver with Mono on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for being absent for a year! Really appreciate your concern.Yes, finally I was able to do it. Downloaded the Mac version of chromedriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html. And simply used it in my C# (mono) code written in the Xamarin Studio. And I was able to invoke the ChromeDriver using the usual "SeleniumDriver = new ChromeDriver(driverLibrary);" statement. But I had to make some more changes in the C# code at multiple places to make the entire Automation framework work on Mac. I forgot the finer details but remember it was fun! People were excited to see Webdriver+Mono doing it on Mac!

Comment: Oh I don't suppose you have any more details on this please? Would be very helpful!